# Is there a way to integrate a Stripe payment on my website with Firebase backend service without using any other backend service?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, stripe-payments

I began to develop an online store website with html, css and js, I use Firebase as backend. Then came up the payment part, I want to use Stripe for that, and it turns out that I have to use Node.js to manage that payment part. (or any other server technology)

I have to say that I'm very novice in back-end (and stripe) and the idea was to get rid of that part (the reason why I use Firebase) except that the payment part requires it.

**My question is:**

*Is it enough to use Firebase only as a backend to manage the payment part with Stripe?*

If no,

*can I use node.js(express framework) just on the payment page and not extend it to all the other pages with those routing things? Or do I have to deploy it on the whole website?*
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Firebase Extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) that is built by Stripe and states:

> Use this extension as a backend for your Stripe payments.

It makes use [restricted API keys](https://stripe.com/docs/keys#limit-access) so you have granular control over what records can be created/read/updated by the extension.

I think that sounds easier that trying to work out an Express app for a single payment page.